# Period background sync does't fire after successfully registered

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm trying to make periodic bg sync where service worker updates badge.
When I run my page and test it via Chrome DevTools, Service worker process the request. But when the page is closed, it doesnt't do anything. Same on mobile phone.

On my page (this part is working and output in console is `periodic update set`):

```
navigator.permissions.query({name:'periodic-background-sync'}).then(function(result) {
  if (result.state === 'granted') {
    console.log('periodic background granted');
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(registration){       
      if ('periodicSync' in registration) {
        try {
          registration.periodicSync.register('update-badge', {
            minInterval:  60 * 60 * 1000,
          }).then(function(ret){
            console.log('periodic update set');
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Periodic background sync cannot be used.');
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Service worker:

```
async function updateBadge() {
  const unreadCount = 5; //fixed value for testing 
  navigator.setAppBadge(unreadCount).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error setting badge.');
  });
}

self.addEventListener('periodicsync', (event) => {
  if (event.tag === 'update-badge') {
    event.waitUntil(updateBadge());
  }
});
```

So when I manually fire background sync from DevTools, badge is set, but not automatically in the background as I thought it will work.

Answer (score 3):

I can't find anything wrong with the code. I've seen variants where you request periodic-background-sync after navigator.serviceWorker.ready but I think that both work (especially since you can trigger the registered event manually).

I think the problem is that not all conditions for periodic background sync to fire are true. These are the conditions from the initial implementation in Chrome (2019):

- Chrome version 80 or later
- The PWA needs to be [installed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Installable_PWAs)
- The website needs to have an engagement score (can be viewed here *chrome://site-engagement/*). Websites with 0 engagement is deleted from the list and won't trigger the periodicsync event, even if it is installed. Once a user hasn’t interacted with a website for 2 hours, its engagement levels begin to decay. With minimal engagement, a periodicsync event will be triggered at an interval of 36h. [source](https://github.com/WICG/background-sync/issues/169#issuecomment-563942794)

In your case I think your code is correct and working but you haven't interacted enough with you app continuously over 36h so the engagement is purged and periodicsync fire timer cancelled (if you have installed your PWA).

For the record, here is a complete working [demo (event registration)](https://github.com/captainbrosset/devtools-tips/blob/a4a5277ee6b67e5cc61eee642bf3d9c68130094f/src/layouts/home.njk#L72) (and [sw code](https://github.com/captainbrosset/devtools-tips/blob/ebfb2c7631464149ce3cc7700d77564656971ff4/src/sw.js#L115)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm testing it in Chrome 98, PWA installed, engagement score (thanks for the link) for this pwa is 27+5 bonus on PC and 0.79 on mobile right now. I've just manually adjusted it to 100 and I'm waiting if smth happens.

Comment: You're welcome! I think it should be around 24h on PC with that engagement score, though I'm not 100% on how the minInterval affects it. I assume it triggers immediately at hour 24 if the periodic sync timer is exceeding minInterval.

Comment: Did something happen @PavelTřupek?

Comment: sorry for delay. Nothing happened at all :(

Answer (score 0):

The specific interval at which the `periodicsync` event is fired varies; what I've seen on, e.g., installed Android web apps is that you'll get `periodicsync` around once a day. It may be different on desktop platforms (and will only happen if your browser is actually running at the time).

Have you waited a full day or so after installing your PWA, and see if it's fired?

Comment: I've waited few days (both desktop and Android) adn nothing happened.

Comment: I'm not sure what might be going on, then. Providing details at https://crbug.com/new is a good next step, as that will get the attention of the folks from the Chrome engineering side of things.

Comment: I don’t understand how it works at all, I also installed the application on my phone, nothing happens